# Custom jQuery plugin returns [object Object]

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am making my own gallery script, but when i try and `alert(this)` it returns [object Object].

I call my function like this

```
$('#images').createGallery({
    server: 'http://localhost/jQuery%20Gallery/images/galleries/',
    galleryName: 'Test',
    galleryWidth: 800,
    galleryImageMargin: 20,
    galleryImageColumns: 2,
    galleryTargetFolder: 'homepage_gallery',
    imageQuality: 100
});
```

and my function's code is this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.createGallery = function(options) {
        alert(this);
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            server: 'http://localhost/jQuery%20Gallery/images/galleries/',
            galleryName: 'Test',
            galleryWidth: 800,
            galleryImageMargin: 20,
            galleryImageColumns: 2,
            galleryTargetFolder: 'homepage_gallery',
            imageQuality: 100
        }, options);

        var galleryImageWidth = settings.galleryWidth / settings.galleryImageColumns;
        var imageUrl = settings.server+settings.galleryTargetFolder;

        var otherMargin = Math.round(settings.galleryImageMargin / 2);
        var finalImageWidth = Math.round(galleryImageWidth - settings.galleryImageMargin);
        var finalImageHeight = Math.round(galleryImageWidth / 1.4);
        var finalGalleryWidth = settings.galleryWidth - settings.galleryImageMargin;

        $('#'+this).before('<style>#'+this+' li:nth-child('+settings.galleryImageColumns+'n+1) { margin-left: 0; } #'+this+' li:first-child { margin-left: 0; } #'+this+' { width: '+finalGalleryWidth+'px; margin: 0px; } #'+this+' li { display: inline-block; list-style: none; margin-left: '+settings.galleryImageMargin+'px; margin-bottom: '+otherMargin+'px; } </style>');

        $.ajax({
            url: imageUrl,
            success: function(data){
                $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
                    // will loop through 
                    var filename = $(this).attr("href");
                    $('<li></li>').html('<img src="thumbnail.php?src='+imageUrl+'/'+filename+'&q='+imageQuality+'&h='+finalImageHeight+'&w='+finalImageWidth+'"/>').appendTo('#'+$(this));
                });
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: And what about `console.log(this)` ??? alert() method only can handle string. And btw, using alert() in debugging purpose is really not recommended because of modal behaviour

Comment: what did you expect `this` to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly correct because `this` refers tot he jQuery wrapper object, whose default to string implementation gives `[object Object]`

If you want to see what is the value of `this` use `console.log(this)` - this makes use of the console provided by the browsers developer tools

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8uLGc/)

Note: Also don't forget to return `this` from the plugin to maintain chainability.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I have done as you said and the object comes out at [ul#images]. How can i now use images as the target id for the gallery?

Comment: @AndyHolmes this question as nothing to do with your opening post, please consider to accept this answer and ask a new question

Comment: Okay, will do in a moment